# Automate assigning plots into different RMarkdown documents

Tags: r, automation, r-markdown

I have a list of plots (100) and I want to assign each 2 plots into one individual rmarkdown and convert them into word documents ultimately. What's the best way I can do this in a loop, function or batch way?

dataframes for plots

```
p1 <- rnorm(3000, 1, 2)
p2 <- rnorm(300, 2, 4)
plot1 <- plot(p1)
plot2 <- hist(p1)
plot3 <- plot(p2, type='l')
plot4 <- hist(p2)
```

code for coverting markdowns

```
library(rmarkdown)

persons <- c("person1", "person2", "person3")

for (person in persons) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = "template.Rmd",
                    output_file = sprintf("%s_report.doc", person),
                    params = list(testperson = person)
  )
}
```

Output expected:

- `person1_report.doc` will contain `plot1` and `plot2`.
- `person2_report.doc` will contain `plot3` and `plot4`.

Comment: has every person his/her own data that creates these two plots, or are the plots just assigned to them one after another?

Comment: Hmm. This is a good question. They're from the same dataset (a big data table) where each person is in one row. @user12256545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this mighty work for you

1. create the .rmd with all the anlysis stuff, plots , etc using parameters for the person in the YAML-header. The params$person can then be used to subset your data for the report and plots.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "user12256545"
date: "14 10 2020"
output: html_document
params:
  person:
    value: 1
    choices: [1,2,3]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

df<- data.frame(person = 1:3, x = rnorm(3), y_value = rnorm(3))
df
```

# The person

```{r}
params$person
```

# plot 

```{r, plot, results='asis'}
# subset the data using the person param:

df_person <- df %>% dplyr::filter(person== params$person) 

# then the plot():

plot(df_person$x,df_person$y_value,
main = paste("Plot for Person",params$person ))

```
````

2. create an additional R script to call the rmarkdown::render function in a loop

```
## 1 write a function to render

render_report = function(person){
  rmarkdown::render(
    "/home/path/to/file.Rmd", params = list(
      person = person
    ),
    output_file = paste0("Report for Person", person, ".html")
  )
}

## use a loop to loop over the function 
## note: 1:3 would be the number of persons (1:100 in your case)

for (i in 1:3) {
  render_report(i)
}
```

Comment: Just double check with the big table today and it works! Many thanks @user12256545